# Scala polymorphic function for filtering an input List of Either

Tags: scala, types, monads, either, parametric-polymorphism

### Seeking a more elegant solution

I have this piece of code, I just use it in test cases where it isn't necessary to do any error handling. What it does is:

- take an input list of strings
- parse them using the DSJSonmapper.parseDSResult method
- filters them and extracts the Right value from each Either (Left is an Exception)

The code is as follows:

```
  def parseDs(ins: List[String]) = {
    def filterResults[U, T](in: List[Either[U, T]]): List[T] = {
      in.filter(y => y.isRight).map(z => z.right.get)
    }
    filterResults(ins.map(x => DSJsonMapper.parseDSResult(x)))
  }
```

Now, I haven't done an awful lot of polymorphic functions, but this works. However I feel like it's a bit ugly. Has anyone got a better suggestion, how to accomplish the same thing.

I'm aware this is going to come down to a case of personal preference. But suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`collect` is made for exactly this kind of situation:

```
def filterMe[U,T](in: List[Either[U,T]]): List[T] = in.collect{
  case Right(r) => r
}
```

In fact, it's so good at this you may want to skip the `def` and just

```
ins.map(DSJsonMapper.parseDsResult).collect{ case Right(r) => r }
```

Answer (score 7):

Rex's answer is possibly a little clearer, but here's a slightly shorter alternative that parses and "filters" in a single step:

```
ins.flatMap(DSJsonMapper.parseDSResult(_).right.toOption)
```

Here we take the [right projection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Either%24%24RightProjection) of each parse result and turn that into an `Option` (which will be `None` if the parse failed and `Some(whatever)` otherwise). Since we're using `flatMap`, the `None`s don't appear in the result and the values are pulled out of the `Some`s.